# Tracking Events with Google Analytics

Tags: javascript, html, google-analytics, event-tracking

There seems to be a well known problem with tracking download events with Safari. I am using Universal Analytics and when using the following code, I see the event correctly if I am using Chrome, IE or FF, but not if using Safari:

```
anchor[i].onclick = function() {
  ga('send', 'event', 'Downloads', 'Click', this.getAttribute('href'));
};
```

*'anchor' is an array returned by document.getElementsByTagName('a')*

From what I have read, Safari is a bit too quick and stops the JavaScript from fully executing when it navigates to the file. This results in not seeing the event in Google Analytics. From Google's own documentation they suggest something similar to this:

```
(function(url) {
  anchor[i].onclick = function() {
    ga('send', 'event', 'Downloads', 'Click', this.getAttribute('href'), {
      'hitCallback': function() {
        document.location = url;
      }
    });
    return false;
  };
})(anchor[i].href);
```

This seems to work in Safari but doesn't produce a very good experience in Internet Explorer as you are now presented with the yellow information bar and don't get the download prompt anymore. If it wasn't for the IE experience this would be my preferred way.

From doing some testing, I noticed that I got events being tracked in Safari if the target of the anchor was '_blank' and this is because the original page is still left processing the JavaScript. At the moment I am using the following workaround:

```
anchor[i].setAttribute('target', '_blank');
anchor[i].onclick = function() {
  ga('send', 'event', 'Downloads', 'Click', this.getAttribute('href'));
};
```

However, this still changes the behaviour in that links open in new windows when they might not have normally.

I have also seen people attach the tracking code to the onMouseDown event, but this isn't 100% reliable - it relies on the fact that this event fires before onClick so adds a little bit of a delay. It could also count false positives when people half click and then change their mind.

So, I am looking to see if anyone has any better suggestions which will work in all cases and on all browsers without changing the user experience?

Comment: Have you come up with an answer to this, yet?

Comment: Nope, I have stuck with opening links in a new window.